# $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(1,0,1,1)$ means there are 4 observed values, blue for the 1st observation … What could (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(1,3,2,2) mean?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

Assume a bag that contains 3 balls. Each ball is either red or blue. The number of blue balls, call it θ, might be 0, 1, 2, or 3. Choose 4 balls at random from the bag with replacement. define the i.i.d. random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, and $X_4$ as follows

\begin{equation}
 X_i = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 &  \qquad \text{if the $i$th chosen ball is blue}  \\
      &  \qquad   \\
    0 &  \qquad \text{if the $i$th chosen ball is red}
  \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

Given $X_i \sim Bernoulli(\frac{\theta}{3})$. I understand $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(1,0,1,1)$ means there are 4 observed values, blue for the 1st observation, red for the 2nd observation, and blue for both 3rd and 4th observation.

Given $X_i \sim Binomial(3, \theta)$ What could $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(1,3,2,2)$ mean?

The question comes from Example 8.8 in [this statistics tutorial](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_2_3_max_likelihood_estimation.php)

Comment: If $x_i$ is Bernoulli, then $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(1,3,2,2)$ doesn't mean anything, it couldn't possibly attain those values. Now, if $x_i$ is Binomial, it makes sense.

Comment: Are you asking for an interpretation on what $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) = (1, 3, 2, 2)$ could mean given $X_i \sim Bin(\theta)$, as stated in Example 8.8? The section preceding Example 8.8 generalizes the concept from a Bernoulli distributed example, and Example 8.8 is no longer related to the example you have quoted in your question.

Comment: @B.Liu Thanks for your reminder. Actually, it comes from Example 8.9

Comment: It means that in the first experiment, you observed 1 blue ball. In the second experiment, you observed 3 blue balls. In the third and fourth experiments, you observed 2 blue balls. Does this answer your question? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki]
(https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you. Please consider moving it to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that in the first experiment, you observed 1 blue ball. In the second experiment, you observed 3 blue balls. In the third and fourth experiments, you observed 2 blue balls.

Comment: Thank you so much. Does 3 in $Binomial(3, \theta)$ mean there are 3 balls in the bag? Note that in the second experiment, 3 blue balls are observed which means there already are 3 blue balls in the bag. If I need to ask this in a new post, please let me know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution